# Using scalaz kleisli without explicit wrapping the function before

Tags: scala, scalaz, function-composition, kleisli

Let's say I have two functions `val f: A => M[B]` and `val g: B => M[C]` where M is monadic. Thus I want to combine them by using kleisli.
What I currently do is this: `kleisliU(f) andThenK g`
But I have not found a way to execute this combination without manually wrapping into kleisli first.

How can write something like `f <???> g` so that `f` is wrapped into kleisli automatically and then combined with `g`? I hope something in scalaz already exists for that and that I don't need to write my own implicit class / conversion.

Just for sake of completeness, that should also work with more functions e.g. `f <???> g <???> h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I wanted the same thing and I did not find it in scalaz, so I just wrote it myself:

```
implicit def toKleisliK[M[_], A, B]: (A => M[B]) => Kleisli[M, A, B] = f => { 
    kleisli[M, A, B](a => f(a)) 
}
// then for example you can write such:
val f: Int => Option[String] = ???
val g: String => Option[Double] = ???
val result = f andThenK g // inferred type is ReaderT[Option, Int, Double]
```